# MacBook says to replace battery. Should I?

Tags: laptop, macbook, hardware-failure, battery

My MacBook says that battery is not charging, and the battery is completely empty (in fact, pressing the button on the battery illuminates no LEDs). If I plug the power adapter off the mac shuts off immediately. I tried with a spare adapter, and it won't charge it.

System information says it has 380 cycles. The battery is 2.5 years old.
System profiler says the battery has 0 mAh of capacity, and that it should be replaced.

Should I just buy a new battery, or should I bring it to an apple point, and leave it there? They can take a look at it (it's on AppleCare), they told me that they will repair it is there is anything wrong with the charging circuit, but they won't give me a new battery. They will keep the laptop for 10 working days at least...

I hate when this happens :P

Comment: The Apple warranty does not cover batteries with more than 300 cycles, so you should skip the repair process and just buy a new battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple Store shouldn't have to keep the machine. If it turns out to a dead battery I'd imagine you'll get a new one on the spot. You could verify it is the battery by swapping in a friend's battery to see if it works, but the chance that this is some other hardware problem is pretty remote. A visit to Apple seems pretty inevitable.

Comment: That's how it should work. But I live in Italy, and there are no apple stores here, only apple resellers. They'll tell you that they are not technicians, and that they need to send your laptop to some other city for evaluation. Moreover the battery is not covered by Apple Care (they say) :(

Comment: Well, I would verify that the battery is dead by borrowing a battery and then just purchase a new one if it is not worth your time to be without the computer. If a different battery works in it then you will have to send it for repairs.

Comment: @ridogi I assume that rather than "If a different battery works..." you meant "If a different battery **does not"* work..."